# How do I configure spring boot default logging pattern in log4j for maven?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I want my maven application logs to be written in below format, I have tried many patterns I know but it didn't print as expected please help me out

```
2019-03-05 10:57:51.112  INFO 45469 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2019-03-05 10:57:51.253  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-05 10:57:51.253  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1358 ms
```

Comment: Hello next time please put the logs pattern you have already tried, it will help people to figure your problem quickly

Answer (score 0):

To achieve use this pattern:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p ${PID:- } --- [%t] %c : %msg%n
```

[More about pattern can be found on this link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-conversion-pattern-example/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but the full package name is getting printed but in the spring boot logging pattern if the package name if lengthy only that starting character of the package name will be logged (for eg : o.s.web.context.ContextLoader), I'm trying to find a pattern like this. please help me out, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the default log4j2 pattern defined in  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml into your log4j2.xml and customise as required